# jQuery method called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a nested bootstrap dropdown in my navbar. Here is the code that prevents the dropdown on click of a nested drop to execute its normal task. This works well.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In this code, `onclick` of the dropdown's `<li>` does something. When the click is on a normal `li` of the dropdown it works fine but when it is in a nested dropdown's li the function is executed but when it ends it is executed again (the onClick). The way I've found to avoid that its complete seconde execution is I check in my if statement `if` `$(this)` (the clicked `li`) is `null`, which it is when it's executed the second time out of nowhere. This way is pretty gross but it works, but does anyone see why the method is called a second time and how to stop it from getting called twice?

```
$("#dropdownViewModeSelect").on('click', 'li', function() {

    selectedViewMode = $(this).attr("viewmode");

    if (selectedViewMode != "undefined" && selectedViewMode != null) 
    {
        if (selectedViewMode != previouslySelectedViewMode || currentTimelineMode != previouslySelectedTimelineMode) 
        {
            //Remove glyphicons to all i
            var touslesideslis = $("#dropdownViewModeSelect li").find("i").removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
            //Add glyphicons to clicked i
            $(this).find("i").addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
            //Add text to button
            currentViewModeSecondary = $(this).attr("viewmodesecondary");
            var textBtn;
            if (currentViewModeSecondary != "classic")
                textBtn = "Ligne du temps - " + $(this).text();
            else
                textBtn = $(this).text();

            $("#dropdownMenuViewMode").text(textBtn);
            $("#dropdownMenuViewMode").append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open pull-left"></span>');
            $("#dropdownMenuViewMode").append('<span class="caret caret-filter"></span>');
            if ($(window).width() >= 768)
                Global.Responsiveness();
        }
    }

});
```

Here's my HTML for the dropdown.

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuViewMode" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open pull-left"></span>Jour<span class="caret"></span></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownViewModeSelect" role="menu">
    <li viewmode="jour" viewmodesecondary="classic"><a id="linkJour">Jour<i class='dropdownFiltreImage glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i></a>
    </li>
    <li viewmode="ressource" viewmodesecondary="classic"><a id="linkRessource">Ressources/Jour<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
    </li>
    <li viewmode="week" viewmodesecondary="classic"><a id="linkSemaine">Semaine<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
    </li>
    <li viewmode="month" viewmodesecondary="classic"><a id="linkMois">Mois<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
    </li>
    <li viewmode="year" viewmodesecondary="classic"><a id="linkAnnee">Année<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
    </li>
    <li viewmode="agenda" viewmodesecondary="classic"><a id="linkAgenda">Agenda<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ligne du temps</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li viewmode="timeline" viewmodesecondary="timeline"><a id="linkTimelineDay">Jour<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
            </li>
            <li viewmode="timeline" viewmodesecondary="timeline"><a id="linkTimelineWeek">Semaine<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
            </li>
            <li viewmode="timeline" viewmodesecondary="timeline"><a id="linkTimelineMonth">Mois<i class='dropdownFiltreImage'></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to stop propagation like in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If your click handler is being called twice it is probably being set twice. Try changing your selector. This may not be the ultimate class structure you want but I'll bet if you add the same class to each of your list elements and then use that class in the selector for the click handler your problem goes away.